# Find all classes, without reasoning

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, rdfs, linked-data

When I have Forward Chaining enabled, I would do:

```
"...WHERE { ?class rdf:type rdfs:Class }"
```

now, I want to do it without the reasoner, so I tried:

```
"...WHERE { ?class rdf:type* rdfs:Class }"
```

but this gave me instances of the classes and not all the classes. For example `rdfs:Resource` is missing. Any ideas? My ontology, if it matters, is [here](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~pms509/2014-2015/projects/hw1/gagOntology.rdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to get a 100%-guaranteed complete result for this without reasoning. For example, `rdfs:Resource` is quite often not explicitly used in a dataset at all, so without reasoning that class simply does not occur in your data. But you can come close enough to completeness for most practical purposes.

When is some resource known to be a class? There are a number of possibilities:

1. when it is of type `rdfs:Class`;
2. when it is the object of an `rdf:type` relation;
3. when it is either the subject or the object of a `rdfs:subClassOf` relation;
4. when it is used as the object of an `rdfs:domain` or `rdfs:range` relation.

So, how to query this? Well the first one is easy:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE { ?c a rdfs:Class }
```

As an aside: in SPARQL, the keyword `a` is a shorthand for the `rdf:type` relation. Note that you do not need to query it transitively (so no `*` is needed).

The second one is also easy:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE { [] rdf:type ?c }
```

The `[]` bit denotes an anonymous variable (since we are not interested in the subject value - we only want the object at this point).

The third one is a little trickier. We can split it up in two parts: first query all resources that are the *subject* of an `rdfs:subClassOf` relation:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE { ?c rdfs:subClassOf [] }
```

Then query all resources that are the *object* of the relation:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE { [] rdfs:subClassOf ?c }
```

Now, let's see if we can combine these two patterns in a single query. We can't just put the two graph patterns in the same WHERE clause just like that, since that would make it a logical AND (meaning we'd only get back those resources that are both subject *and* object of a subclass relation). So we need to use a logical OR. In SPARQL this can be done with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT ?c 
WHERE { 
    { ?c rdfs:subClassOf [] }
    UNION
    { [] rdfs:subClassOf ?c }
}
```

However, in this case we can also express the logical OR in a different way, using a property path expression, like so:

```
SELECT ?c 
WHERE { ?c rdfs:subClassOf|^rdfs:subClassOf [] }
```

The path expression `p1|p2` means "match with any of these two relations". The operator `^` says "query the inverse of the relation". So if we put this together, the above path expression says "match with any triples where the subject is `?c` and the relation is `rdfs:subClassOf`, or where the relation `rdfs:subClassOf` is inverted and thus the *object* matches with `?c`".

We can query the fourth possibility in a similar fashion:

```
SELECT ?c 
WHERE { [] rdfs:domain|rdfs:range ?c }
```

### Putting it all together

```
SELECT ?c 
WHERE { 
     { ?c a rdfs:Class } 
     UNION 
     { [] rdf:type ?c }
     UNION
     { [] rdfs:domain|rdfs:range ?c }
     UNION
     { ?c rdfs:subClassOf|^rdfs:subClassOf [] }         
}
```

This can probably be shortened further. And of course you can simplify it further if you know your ontology well (for example if you know you never use domain or range properties, you can leave out that bit).

Comment: Yes, it found less, but it get me to know how to approach and will work on to try to find the others, thanks!

Comment: You are missing the `rdfs:Resource`. This shouldn't be easy to get? I mean it's the superclass of all. Sorry if I am telling silly things, but I am really new to this!

Comment: As said: if you don't have reasoning enabled, the only way `rdfs:Resource` would be present for querying is if some triple in your original data _explicitly_ mentions it (e.g. if it has a triple `ex:r1 rdf:type rdfs:Resource`). If that is the case, the above query will capture it. But if not, then it won't be retrieved. You can't query what isn't there :)